# PHP problem with Bulgarian-MIK character set, cant get one letter

Tags: php, character-encoding

I know that Bulgarian-MIK character set can be converted with the ord function and adding 64, and the bulgarian-MIK characters are from 127 to 191 but i cant get the letter "а"(ord - 127).I tried a lot of ways but it seems that php is processing "а" with a blank symbol and i cant get it.

```
 define("PHP_NL", "<br>"); 
$string  = '--------------  1 --------------'.PHP_NL;
$string .= '413 …±Ї°Ґ±® €¶®        X1.000'.PHP_NL;
$string .= '358 ЊЁ­ ‚®¤  0.5       X1.000'.PHP_NL;
$string .= '--------------------------------'.PHP_NL;
$string .= '1 -Ђ¤°Ё ­  - ЊЂ‘Ђ: 1 - 6'.PHP_NL;
$string .= '17-08-2018       09:05:32'.PHP_NL;
$string .= '--------------------------------';
```

That is my string with Bulgarian-MIK encoding.I tried to convert it and i every letter is converted fine, but only "а" i cant get.
My function

```
function ConvertDosToWin($string) {

    $chr = null;

    for ($i = 1;$i<strlen($string);$i++) {

        $chr = mb_convert_encoding($string[$i],'utf-8','windows-1251');
        if((ord($chr) >= 127) && (ord($chr)<=(127+64)) ) {
            echo 'inside if';
            $string[$i] = chr(ord($chr)+64);
        }

    }
    return $string;
  }
```

Comment: Range is [128 .. 191], or at least that's how I used to do it.

Comment: Yes i managed to get it but now i got problem with converting the windows-1251 to Bulgarian MIK

Answer (score 0):

I think that this approach may help. I used this in an old project and next is working example. PHP file is `Windows-1251` encoded. If your text is in different encoding, you need to convert text using `mb_convert_encoding()` or `iconv()`, because `ord()` returns the binary value of the first byte of text as an unsigned integer between 0 and 255.

Test.php:

```
<?php
// Functions
function ConvertDosToWin($string) {
    $chr = null;
    for ($i = 0; $i<strlen($string); $i++) {
        if ((ord($chr) >= 128) && (ord($chr) <= 191)) {
            $string[$i] = chr(ord($chr) + 64);
        }
    }
    return $string;
}
function ConvertWinToDos($string) {
    $chr = null;
    for ($i = 0; $i<strlen($string); $i++) {
        $chr = $string[$i];
        if ((ord($chr) >= 192) && (ord($chr) <= 255)) {
            $string[$i] = chr(ord($chr) - 64);
        }
    }
    return $string;
}

// Output    
$text = 'АБВГДЕЖЗИЙ';
$text = ConvertWinToDos($text);
file_put_contents('dos.txt', $text);
?>
```

Comment: i still cant convert from Win to Dos, function return way different symbols

Comment: @SebastianJeliazkov Try without 'mb_convert_encoding`.

Comment: Still not working i cant understand where the function is getting not the right symbols

Comment: @SebastianJeliazkov Check how your PHP file is encoded. If file is UTF-8 encoded, just execute `$string = mb_convert_encoding($string,'utf-8','windows-1251');` and remove `mb_convert_encoding` from your functions.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem using iconv.

```
   function ConvertWinToDos($string) {
    $chr = null;
    for ($i = 1;$i<strlen($string);$i++) {
        $string = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($string,mb_detect_order(),true),'windows-1251',$string);
        $chr = $string[$i];
        if ((ord($chr) >= 192) && (ord($chr) <= 255)) {
            $string[$i] = chr(ord($chr) - 64);
        }
    }

    return $string;
}
```

Comment: You may consider to put $string = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($string,mb_detect_order(),true),'windows-1251',$string); before your for loop. `strlen()` returns the number of bytes rather than the number of characters in a string. Also you'll miss the first character with `for ($i = 1; $i < strlen(); $i++)`. Thanks.